# Symfony 3 - Form with OneToMany association in database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I work on a OneToMany association in my database. This association work perfectly when I try to add data from fixtures and when I try to return data from database.

The problem is with my FormType CommandType which does'nt work. Symfony and Doctrine return this error message :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO command_product (quantity, command_id, product_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [3, null, 1]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'command_id' cannot be null

CommandType's code :

```
class CommandType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('establishment', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Company::class,
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('dateCreation', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('contains', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => CommandProductType::class,
                'required' => true,
                'allow_add' => true
            ))
            ->add('state',TextType::class, array(
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('totalAmount', MoneyType::class, array(
                'required' => true
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Command::class
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_command';
    }
}
```

CommandProductType's code :

```
class CommandProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('quantity', NumberType::class, array(
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'    => Product::class,
                'required' => true
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => CommandProduct::class
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_commandproduct';
    }
}
```

Command's code class :

```
class Command
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Company $establishment
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="establishment_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $establishment;

    /**
     * @var DateTime $dateCreation
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreation", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Type("datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @var string $state
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var float $totalAmount
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="totalAmount", type="float", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="float")
     */
    private $totalAmount;

    /**
     * @var mixed $contains
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CommandProduct", mappedBy="contain", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $contains;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->contains = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var CommandProduct $commandProduct
     */
    public function addContain(CommandProduct $commandProduct = null)
    {
        $commandProduct->setContain($this);

        $this->contains->add($commandProduct);
    }

    /**
     * @param CommandProduct $commandProduct
     */
    public function removeContain(CommandProduct $commandProduct)
    {
        if ($this->contains->contains($commandProduct)) {
            $this->contains->removeElement($commandProduct);
        }
    }
}
```

CommandOrder's code class :

```
class CommandProduct
{
    /**
     * @var int $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Command $contain
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Command", inversedBy="contains")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="command_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $contain;

    /**
     * @var int $quantity
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"default": 1})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="int")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var Product $product
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */    
    private $product;
}
```

Comment: I think it needs to be $`builder->add('contain' ...` the point being that it should match the property name so `contain` not `contains`. Not 100% sure though...

Comment: The error message couldn't be clearer. When you read it and got to `Column 'command_id' cannot be null` and saw that the code tries to insert null to a non nullable column, did that bring your closer to the problem / solution?

Comment: You can try to pass the parameter `by_reference` with the `false` value in the "contains" field options (symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/…). This will call the `setContain` method in your `CommandProduct` class.

Comment: The problem is : why `contain` in `CommandProduct` doesn't contain the `Command` object which creates before in the form ? By default, I use a `foreach` in my controller but I need to understand the problem and fix it. Your solution is not work @Bananaaple beacause I have only get method to return `contains` attribute in `Command`. Could you give me a concrete exemple for your solution @Exiam because the exemple in Symfony documentation is not clear (they use a `?`as data in `by_reference` FormType option ?

Comment: @NBoulfroy Here is the example (for your `CommandType` class) : https://twitter.com/dawn_noreply/status/1012360771785773056

Comment: Thx to @Exiam for his help, your solution work perfectly!